# upgarde magento 2.1.5 to 2.2

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

Does anyone know what are the meaning of the messages? Not successful? How to upgrade?

```
sh-4.2$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
./composer.json has been updated
sh-4.2$ composer update
No patches supplied.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable                                             by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 10                                            0.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfi                                            able by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2                                            , 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc2 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfi                                            able by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2                                            , 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc3 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfi                                            able by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2                                            , 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable                                             by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 10                                            0.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable                                             by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 10                                            0.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.0.0 -> satisfiable by                                             magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-                                            community-edition[2.2.0].
    - Installation request for magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/modu                                            le-wishlist-sample-data[100.1.1, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0].
```

Comment: I am also having same kind of error, and I have reported this problem earlier,     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198515/magento-2-2-0-upgrade-error

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution :

1. **Remove from your composer.json all the sample data modules.**
   php bin/magento sampledata:remove
2. Run composer update.
3. Run "php -f bin/magento sampledata:deploy" **this will add the latest sample data modules to your composer.json based on your M2 version.**

perfect solution available here : [Upgrade Magento from 2.1 to 2.2.1 with sample data using composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/upgrade-magento-from-2-1-to-2-2-1-with-sample-data-using-composer)