# Component dependency failure on 2.2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, bin-magento

Please view the attached image for details:

When I want to install update from my Magento marketplace, it gives me the attached error.

[image]

Comment: Check the following link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198515/magento-2-2-0-upgrade-error

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I've been away from office this past few days. this didn't work for me. I am using Magento 2.2 and I try the steps it just mess my website. Any other suggestion or help on this problem please. thank you so much I've been stuck here for how many days. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am installing the MIGS service for payment gateway and it gives me this error. I am just connecting my username from my Magento market place.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade via the command line? It looks like you have additional modules that are not compatible with 2.2